# UIToolbar in UISplitView application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am trying to show the UIToolBar in the RootView of a UISplitView application, the code is the following:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
UIBarButtonItem *refreshItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh 
                                                      target:self 
                                                      action:@selector(refresh:)];    
self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:refreshItem, nil];
[refreshItem release];
```

However, what I see is:

[image]

There's black bar on top (I don't know where this came from, I don't need this) also the bar at the bottom, is there a way to resize it?

What I want is to get something like this:
[image]

Comment: The code you posted looks okay.  The problem may have nothing to do with the toolbar.  There seems to be a gap both at the top and at the bottom, between the table view and both the navigation bar and the toolbar.  Can you post the code where you set up and size the table view, or the code where you set up the split view controller, the navigation controller and the root view controller?  The problem may be there.

Comment: I set up the UISplitView controller directly using their own template

Comment: How do you set up the table view?  It looks like there's a gap between the table view's frame & both the navigation bar & toolbar.  I'm just guessing.  Anyway, forgive the repetition, but the toolbar code you posted looks fine.

Comment: well...I am just starting a new UISplitView application, changed nothing else and then did a self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO; and that's what I got

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using something like this you can add a bar button item to the top of the controller:

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = refreshItem;
[refreshItem release];
```

You will make the button appear in the main view controller's title bar, as it's meant to be.

If you want to make the button appear in the bottom of the navigation controller you could try using this approach, instead:

```
UIBarButtonItem *refreshItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:refreshItem, nil animated:YES]];
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO]; //optional, don't remember if it's required ...
[refreshItem release];
```

For this piece of code to work correctly the side controller has to be a UINavigationController, otherwise you wouldn't be able to create and handle the toolbar. I tried this approach in a clean project and the toolbar renders perfectly.

Comment: not really...what I want is the refreshItem to appear as it is now, however I want to eliminate the top black bar and resize the bottom bar to an appropriate size

Comment: Probably you can create a custom UIToolbar object and add it as a subview to the side controller.

Comment: hmm..can you give me a code sample on how to do that? I am confused on how to add it to the bottom

Comment: I have included a picture above on what I really want to do

Comment: I updated the answer. It seems like your approach is the correct one, but in a clean project it does not give problems. You should check your side view controller definition. Is it a UINavigationController?

Comment: Can you please post the code you use to initialize the split view controller, the side and detail controllers?

Comment: You should really start again from scratch. I tried my solution right now and it works correctly. Probably there are problems in the initialization of the root controller. Without any code insight I cannot help you ...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and Just fixed it, Due to moving the code out of the Viewdid Load to lower down the Page,

As I had previous put in

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem {
```

Moving the Code You used to under that, Worked and fixed the issue

Stewart

Answer (score 1):

Just a note for anybody else who stumbles upon this question. I was having the same issue as adit. The problem turned out to be I was setting up and unhiding the toolbar in the `viewDidLoad` method instead of the `viewWillAppear` method. Those gaps are caused by setting up the toolbar before the view knows it's being displayed in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

The safest and easiest solution is to setup the `UINavigationController` to display the toolbar and navigation bar in Interface Builder.

If it looks as expected in IB, it is very unlikely it will change at run-time.

If the toolbar is to be shown/hidden when navigating you should add the cod to do so in `viewWillAppear:` and **allways** call the super implementation, or unexpected things may occurs. Something like this tends to give the best results in a consistent manner:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated;
{
    [super viewWillApplear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO
                                       animated:animated];
}
```

Also make sure to show/hide the toolbar as need in `viewWillAppear:` for all view controllers in your navigation stack for best result.